# AudioKit bounce recording sync

Tags: ios, swift, audiokit, avaudioengine

I need help with an issue... I am recording a bounce with renderToFile, in AudioKit 4 and an artist has complained that the different tracks are not aligned to the sample. In preRender, we have a list of players with the different tracks and records that are set to play in succession, the problem is that I cannot set the AVAudioTime scheduling because it crashes, I suppose due to the fact of the engine being in manualrenderingmode. Is there a way to sync them to the sample? I suppose this is an issue tied to the underlaying AVAudioEngine...

I cannot use AVMutableComposition because we need the recording to be exactly as the one played by AudioKit, and volume would differ.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced random crashes after setting offline rendering mode, as well as after going back to online rendering mode after being offline.

This situation seems to be triggered by this kind of conditions:

- Setting offline rendering mode when the engine hasn't completely finished processing.
- Start processing right after calling `disableManualRenderingMode`, without giving enough time for the engine to start.

A partial workaround I've found is to wait some time before setting offline mode, as well as waiting a small time interval after going online. So I have functions in my code as follows:

```
func setOnlineMode(successCompletion: @escaping() -> Void, failCompletion: @escaping() -> Void) {
    AKManager.engine.stop()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5, execute: {
        AKManager.engine.disableManualRenderingMode()
        do {
            try AKManager.engine.start()
        } catch {
            print("failed to start engine")
            failCompletion()
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.5, execute: {
            successCompletion()
        })
    })
}
```

I also try to avoid resetting the engine after going to offline mode:

```
    /* From AudioKit renderToFile function */
    try AKTry {
        // Engine can't be running when switching to offline render mode.
        if self.isRunning { self.stop() }
        try self.enableManualRenderingMode(.offline, format: audioFile.processingFormat, maximumFrameCount: maximumFrameCount)

        // This resets the sampleTime of offline rendering to 0.
        self.reset() /* I don't do this */
        try self.start()


    }
```

To be honest, I've heavily modified my code to avoid going back and forth between online and offline mode. I only do it now at one point in my app, after a delay as explained above.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the same I'm asking, but thanks.